# How can I do NonlinearModelFit for only specific parameters?

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I have a two dimensional data of the form $$\{x,y,f[x,y]\}$$. For example,

```
data = {{1, 9.4, 14.4}, {1, 5.6, 11.1}, {2, 3.1, 6.5}, {2, 
4.7, 11.1}, {3, 2., 6.8}, {3, 6.2, 11.1}, {4, 6.9, 12.4}, {4,
 1.5, 8.9}, {5, 0.2, 8.6}, {5, 2.1, 11.4}, {6, 9.3, 
11.8}, {6, 2.5, 10.9}};
```

But, I want to do NonlinearModelFit to only for the second term of the list as a parameter and get list of the function as the form $$f_x(y)$$
Is there some nice approach to get the list of functions $f_1(y),f_2(y),f_3(y)..$?

Comment: Try `MultiNonlinearModelFit`:  https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultiNonlinearModelFit.

Comment: A clarification:  If there are common parameters among the functions **and** the error variance is identical for all functions, then `MultiNonlinearModelFit` is a good choice.  But if the functions are completely separate, then @MichaelSeifert 's answer is the way to go.

Comment: My problem doesn't have a same error variance and completely separable. So, I think I'll first try with MichaelSeifert's answer. But it's first time to see there's MultiNonlinearModelFit. Thank you @JimB :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have more than two data points for each `x` in your real data set, or this will be a pretty easy fit for Mathematica to do. I also assume that the fits $f_1$, $f_2$, ... do not have any parameters in common;  in other words, the parameters in each function are independent of each other.

With those caveats, here's an approach:

- Gather the data into sublists according to their first element:

  ```
  sorteddata = GatherBy[data, First]
  ```
- Define a simple function to test out the curve fitting:

  ```
  f[x_, y_, a_, b_] = x + a Sin[b y]
  ```
- Define a function that does the following:  takes a list of triples of the form $\{x_i, y_i, f_i\}$, with all $x_i$ equal;  drop the first element from each of the triples to serve as the data being fitted;  and invoke `f` with $x_1$ as the `x` parameter in `f`.  Then apply this function to each of the elements in `sorteddata`.

  ```
  fit[triples_] := NonlinearModelFit[(Drop[#, 1] &) /@ triples, f[triples[[1, 1]], y, a, b], {a, b}, y]
  fitlist = fit /@ sorteddata
  ```

  [image]
- How did we do?

  ```
  Table[Show[Plot[fitlist[[i]][y], {y, 0, 10}], 
             ListPlot[sorteddata[[i, All, 2 ;; 3]], PlotStyle -> Red,  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}],
             PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, 6}]
  ```

[image]

Comment: Aha!! Thank you for very kind explanation :)